# Is god just a matter of interpretation?

Tags: theology, universe

The common definition of god is that he is all knowing and all powerful, yet he has a personality (merciful etc.), but in my mind those two things conflict with eachother.

First off he is all knowing therefore he cannot possibly have a personality or character associated with him, a personality is built upon decisions, what decisions we make based on the input given to us is what defines a personality (not only human, this can be aplied to anything with a presumed personality).

But a god who is all knowing will never have to make a choice because he already knows the outcome of every choice he can make (every possible choice).
One could argue that the existance of information about said outcome defines its existance.
If a being truly knows all and knowlage defines existance then an infinite amount of universes must exist (some completely different down to the laws of physics).

Could one argue that the universe is not a construct created by god, but the universe (all versions of it) ARE god?

And if so, we are all a part of god, yey.

Comment: Your question builds on several big terms like "all knowing", "all powerfull", "personality", "existence", "god", "universe". It seems difficult to reply as long as these terms remain undefined. E.g., do you assume that "all knowing" means also knowing future events? Would you please add a quote to which definitions or passage from the literature you refer, thanks.

Comment: There is no logic behind the idea that one cannot both be correct and have style.  Decisions are not binary, and knowledge does not predetermine choice.  There is not always a "right thing to do", and one need not always do the right thing, if one is God -- whatever God chooses would automatically be right.  So you argument does not move me.  And it is unrelated to your opening title, or to your concluding questions, which many people, from Hegel to the Upanishads to Terrence McKenna have all answered 'yes' in different ways.  Do you want to make this three different questions?

Comment: Say, there was a God, or gods; and you having witnessed this as a revelation, are then sent to be the bearer of this news to an uncomprehending people - your own people, so you know them; how would you explain, if you were only to use words? Mercy, must apply in two senses, one for a god, or God; the other for a man or a king - the human sense; but we, being human, cannot transcend our humanness, ordinarily speaking; hence already the awkwardness, the great gaps & fissures that can open up in communication of this kind.

Comment: @JoWehler When I say "all knowing", it is meant to convey that he knows:
everything that was, could have been, is, could be, will be, could be (in the future), the knowlage of these things defines their existance so an infinite amount of universes exist with an infinite amount of variables.
From there comes the "he cannot have a personality" because he knows the outcome of every decision he can make and if he knows it then it exists, therefore the decision is already made in one (or more) of the infinite possible universes.

Answer (score 2):

> he cannot possibly have a personality or character associated with him, a personality is built upon decisions, what decisions we make based on the input given to us is what defines a personality

What you are referring to here is [the bundle theory of self](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Hume#The_self), which not every one subscribes to. In particular, someone who believes in God is likely a dualist, and dualism provides a situation where one can have a specific personality and character independent of experiences and perceptions. See for example Leibniz's soul monads.

> Could one argue that the universe is not a construct created by god, but the universe (all versions of it) ARE god?

This is known as [pantheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism), and has adherents even among certain interpretations of the monotheistic religions.